# java - Get the list of usernames who were online

Tags: java, session, servlets

I would like to get the list of users online. In the link http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jsp-servlet-session-listener-tutorial-example-in-eclipse-tomcat/ I could see the code that is used to get the count of users online.

I think I need to have an ArrayList that gets and stores the the usernames in sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) and then display this list.

Please suggest if this is the correct method or if there is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new Listener similar that:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SessionCounter implements HttpSessionListener {
    private List sessions = new ArrayList();


public SessionCounter() {
}

public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    HttpSession session = event.getSession();
    sessions.add(session.getId());

    session.setAttribute("counter", this);
}

public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    HttpSession session = event.getSession();
    sessions.remove(session.getId());

    session.setAttribute("counter", this);
}

public int getActiveSessionNumber() {
    return sessions.size();
}
}
```

After that you add this class to web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
           SessionCounter
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Now when you can count no of active user:

```
 SessionCounter counter = (SessionCounter) session.getAttribute("counter");
 counter.getActiveSessionNumber()
```

Comment: But I need to get the usernames

Comment: I think this solution could be dangerous because you don't have any kind of synchronization and it could happen that two threads / requests create a new session and thus modify the `sessions` list simultaneously.